# How to handle png generation with changing frame buffer size?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I am writing some unit tests for my drawing code. The steps include:

1. Setting up GLFW window and context

   ```
   glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
   glfwGetWindowSize(window, &window_width, &window_height);        
   glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &frame_buffer_width, &frame_buffer_height);
   ```
2. Perform drawings

   ```
   beginFrame(); 
   // perform drawing..     
   endFrame();
   ```
3. Output what has been drawn to a png file (using stb_image_write).

   ```
   stbi_write_png(file_name, frame_buffer_width, frame_buffer_height, 4, image.get(), frame_buffer_width * 4);
   ```
4. Compare the generated png with a reference image (using pixel comparison of the images).

The problem I encounter is **frame_buffer_width** and **frame_buffer_height** are not always consistent. To be more particular, sometimes they are 1:1 to the window size, sometimes their sizes are doubled. This makes the tests fail because the generated png is not always the same (while the reference image size is constant). And writing to png using window_width and window_height is not a correct way to do.

According to GLFW documentation [link](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/window_guide.html).

> The size of a framebuffer may change independently of the size of a window.

I also read somewhere that for macOS specifically, the frame buffer size can be double of the window size.

How can I solve the issue with changing frame buffer size?

Comment: You could scale the output image before writing to file or at least before comparing it in the test. The test should consider a certain tolerance then because I assume the scaling might cause some small deviation from the expected result (regardless of which kind of interpolation is used in scaling).

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Thanks! I will try that. Do you know when frame buffer size would change? I expect it to change running on different screens. I have been running the tests for an hour, and the frame buffer size does not change anymore...  For example, glfwGetWindowContentScale(window, scaleX, scaleY). scaleX and scaleY are 2 when I run the tests on my macbook screen. While they are both 1 if I run the test on an external screen I plugged into my macbook. Not sure if this relates somehow to the problem.

Comment: The only reason, I could imagine, that this has to do with super sampling (used to achieve anti-aliasing).

Comment: Often the width (or the pitch) of the frame buffer needs to a power of 2 (or some multiple). Is the image staying the same logical size -- if so then you just need to handle larger pitches in the code that extracts pixels from the frame buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relying on the default framebuffer for testing is wrong for multiple reasons. Other than the undetermined size, the bit-depth can change too, as well as some pixels may fail the pixel-ownership test.

Instead, for unit-testing purposes, refactor your rendering code so it can render to an off-screen FBO. Then you can create an FBO of a determined size and format, render to it, and save it to a file.

Comment: I follow you suggestion in the end. It works nicely. Thanks!